# collapse previous group when i click on other group item in Grid view in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My `.aspx` page code is below mentioned. In this I bind some products to parent `grid(grdPBase)` some products to its `childgrid(grdPFamily)` in the same manner i added some products to their child grids also.

The problem is if I click on first plus symbol then except that current plus symbol remaining all should be in collapsable mode.

```
<div id="style_1" class="scrollbar h450">
            <asp:GridView ID="grdPBase" runat="server" class="font15" margin-left="10px" paddding-left="15px"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="ProductID" ShowHeader="False" OnRowDataBound="OngrdPBaseRowDataBound"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="OngrdPBaseSelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPFamilyShow" runat="server" OnClick="imgPFamilyShow_Click"
                                class="outlinenone" ImageUrl="~/Images/plus.png" CommandArgument="Show" />
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPFamily" runat="server">
                                <asp:GridView ID="grdPFamily" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="OngrdPFamilyRowDataBound"
                                    margin-left="10px" paddding-left="15px"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="OngrdPFamilySelectedIndexChanged" class="font15 mtop8 mleft10"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ProductID" GridLines="None"
                                    ShowHeader="False">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="hs">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPClassShow" runat="server" OnClick="imgPClassShow_Click"
                                                    class="outlinenone" ImageUrl="~/Images/plus.png" CommandArgument="Show" />
                                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlPClass" runat="server">
                                                    <asp:GridView ID="grdPClass" runat="server" class="mtop8 font15"
                                                        DataKeyNames="ProductID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OngrdPClassRowDataBound"
                                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="OngrdPClassSelectedIndexChanged" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False">
                                                        <Columns>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="hs">
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPLineShow" runat="server" OnClick="imgPLineShow_Click" class="outlinenone"
                                                                        ImageUrl="~/Images/plus.png" CommandArgument="Show" />
                                                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPLine" runat="server">
                                                                        <asp:GridView ID="grdPLine" runat="server" class="mtop10 font15"
                                                                            DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnRowDataBound="OngrdPLineRowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OngrdPLineSelectedIndexChanged"
                                                                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False">
                                                                            <Columns>
                                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="PLineID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="PLineName" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                                                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPLine" class="Plinecolor" Text="" ForeColor="#800000"
                                                                                            Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
                                                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeletePLine" runat="server" class="font12" OnClick="lnkDeletePLine_Click"
                                                                                            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')">
                                                                                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                            </Columns>
                                                                        </asp:GridView>
                                                                    </asp:Panel>
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="PClassID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="PClassName" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPClass" class="Pclasscolor" ForeColor="Blue" Font-Size="15px"
                                                                        Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeletePClass" runat="server" class="font12" OnClick="lnkDeletePClass_Click"
                                                                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')">
                                                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        </Columns>
                                                    </asp:GridView>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="PFamilyID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="PFamilyName" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPFamily" ForeColor="#800000" class="font14" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeletePFamily" runat="server" class="font12" OnClick="lnkDeletePFamily_Click"
                                                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')">
                                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="PBaseID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="PBaseName" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPBase" class="Pbasecolor font15" Text="" ForeColor="#3e3e5b"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeletePBase" runat="server" class="font12" Font-Bold="true"
                                OnClick="lnkDeletePBase_Click"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
```

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but I do not see any C in this question.  It would be greatly appreciated for you to [edit] the question and remove the C tag as it appears to be irrelevant.  Thank you!